# How can I save data entered through a user macro in Confluence?

Tags: java, wiki, confluence

I am creating a user macro for Confluence used for inline commenting. The user will be able to enter some text related to a certain paragraph and this information is then saved. My current problem is that I don't know where or how to save the information entered by the user through this macro.

My idea was to modify the $body of the macro through the macro but I have found no way to do this. I have created a function that is supposed to save this data (somewhere):

```
function post_reply() {
    var f = document.getElementById("comment_content");
    var g = document.getElementById("new_comment");
    $body += "<br> $action.remoteUser.fullName: " + f.value; 
    f.value="";
    g.style.display= "none";
}
```

This does not work so I need your help.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, sounds like you need to write an add-on proper for that. User macros won't be any good for manipulating the page content after a "form submit".

An [add-on](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-plugin-guide/writing-confluence-plugins) would be much more powerful and allow you to achieve your goal ;)